# Anti-aliased Fonts in Animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an animation with two subplots--one 3D and another 2D.  I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to get better font rendering from the 2D axes however.  I tried playing around with various settings with [font_manager](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiEh7udvJbIAhUWEpIKHT9kAOI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatplotlib.org%2Fapi%2Ffont_manager_api.html&usg=AFQjCNFHy8nsxcifzWblNS7tMe-YhlMPvw&sig2=YWN8B2U49M8ABJK2YF54Sw), and even changing the [frame_format](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FileMovieWriter.frame_format) to raw, but I've had no success.  Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?  I get the same results with mpeg4.

The strange thing is that the 3D figure seems to render the font properly.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

w, h = matplotlib.figure.figaspect(.5)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w,h))

ax3d  = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax2d  = fig.add_subplot(122)

ax3d.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax3d.set_ylim(-3, 3)
ax3d.azim = -90
ax3d.elev = 0
ax3d.set_title('Car on Parking Ramp')

ax2d.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax2d.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax2d.set_ylabel('y')
ax2d.set_xlabel('x')
ax2d.set_title('Intersection with z=0')

''' Helix '''
K = 3          ## Angular velocity
H = 2*np.pi    ## Height

t = np.linspace(0, H, 100, endpoint=True)

x = np.cos(K*t)
y = np.sin(K*t)
z = H - t

ax3d.plot(x, y, z, color='k')

''' z = 0 Plane '''
xx, yy = np.meshgrid([-20,20], [-20,20])
ax3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, 0, alpha=0.3, facecolor='b', rstride=1, cstride=1, shade=True)
ax3d.set_axis_off()

''' Tangent Line Data '''
xdata = np.array([ np.cos(K*t), np.cos(K*t) - K*(H - t)*np.sin(K*t) ])
ydata = np.array([ np.sin(K*t), np.sin(K*t) + K*(H - t)*np.cos(K*t) ])

''' Graph Lines '''
proj,     = ax2d.plot([],[])
tangent,  = ax3d.plot([], [], [], color='b')


def update_graph(n, tangent, proj, xdata, ydata):    
    tangent.set_data(xdata[:,n],
                     ydata[:,n])

    tangent.set_3d_properties([H - t[n], 0])

    proj.set_xdata(xdata[1,:n])
    proj.set_ydata(ydata[1,:n])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, len(t), 
                              fargs=(tangent, proj, xdata, ydata), interval=75, blit=True)

ani.save('im.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=10)
#ani.save('im.mp4', extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

For people who face the same issue, it's indeed related to matplotlib backend.

Using different backend might help. In my case,  the

```
%matplotlib nbagg
```

solved it (thanks to the linked question: [Pixelated fonts when plot is saved as jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283274/pixelated-fonts-when-plot-is-saved-as-jpeg)) .