# Pixelated fonts when plot is saved as jpeg

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

When I save a matplotlib figure as a jpeg the tick fonts are pixelated.  I'm not sure what is going on or if there is any hack to fix this.  Does anyone have any insight?

```
%matplotlib nbagg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1.2,1.2,1000,endpoint=True)
y = np.copy(x)

x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z   = -x**2 + y**2 - y**3

fig = plt.figure()

ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

CS = plt.contour(x,y,z, [0,-0.1,0.1], colors=['black','blue', 'gray'])
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=14, inline=1, fmt='%1.1f', manual=[(-0.15,0), (-0.4,0), (0.25,0.5)])

plt.savefig('plot.png', format='png')
plt.savefig('plot.jpg', format='jpg')
plt.savefig('plot.tiff', format='tiff')
```

Here is plot.png:

[image]

Here is plot.jpg:

[image]

Here is the plot.tiff:

[image]

I believe this is related to a previous question I had: [Anti-aliased Fonts in Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804900/anti-aliased-fonts-in-animation)

Comment: have you tried a different backend? I seem to get the same results as you with `nbagg`, but with `Agg` my jpg looks much better. With the `MacOSX` backend both the jpg and the tiff have the pixellated fonts

Comment: Yes that does seem to help.  I got rid of '%matplotlib nbagg' and added 'matplotlib.use('webagg')' and I got a jpg that looks identical to the png and tiff.  This will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @tom, thanks again.  I was stuck and couldn't figure out what to do.  Your suggestion definitely pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

As noted above, this situation appears is dependent on the backend used.  You can avoid the issue by using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('webagg')
```

as opposed to:

```
%matplotlib nbagg
```

I believe the issue has to do with PIL trying to save a jpeg of a figure with transparency.  If you insist on using nbagg, it appears that if you set:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['nbagg.transparent'] = False
```

Your jpeg image fonts won't be pixelated and will look nearly identical to the png and tiff files shown in the question.  Unfortunately using the rcParams:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.transparent'] = False
```

is not sufficient.  It appears that the 'savefig.transparent' rcParam will control the transparency of the plot inside the figure and the 'nbagg.transparent' will control the transparency outside of the figure (ie: axis, ticks, titles, etc..).  There is probably an easy work by ensuring the backend forces transparency = False for when saving to file formats that don't support transparency.

Some of the other backends may not support transparency which is why it appears to fix the problem when you change backends.

I will report this to github as a bug.